# If $G$ is an abelian group and $G/H\cong G$, under what conditions does this imply $H=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ such that $G/H\cong G$. What conditions on $G$ will force $H=0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is sufficient that $G$ be finitely generated. Consider the classification of finitely generated abelian groups: if the non-trivial subgroup $H$ contained any non-torsion element, then the rank of $G/H$ would be strictly less than that of $G$, hence $G/H\not\cong G$; but if $H$ is torsion, then the cardinality of the torsion subgroup of $G/H$ would be strictly less than the cardinality of the torsion subgroup of $G$, hence $G/H\not\cong G$.

Many non-finitely-generated abelian groups $G$ have non-trivial subgroups $H$ such that $G/H\cong G$, such as
$$G=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\cdots,\qquad H=\mathbb{Z}\oplus 0\oplus0 \oplus \cdots$$
However, there are some non-finitely generated abelian groups $G$ for which it still happens to be true that $G/H\cong G\implies H=0$. A nice example that Carl points out below is
$$G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\oplus\cdots$$

Comment: For your necessary claim, what about $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots$?

Comment: @Carl: Thanks, I didn't think that through fully. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @ Zev Chonoles If $G$ is divisible, then $H=0$?

Comment: @aliakbar: Take infinite direct sum of additive groups of rational numbers.